# tvOS UITabBarController doesn't show TabBarItems of Storyboard Reference

Tags: tvos

1. UITabBarController with Storyboard-Reference to the initialViewController of Hello.storyboard as a tabBarItem(Relationship Segue) in Main.storyboard.
   [image: Main.storyboard]
2. Inside Hello.storyboard, I have a plain ViewController which I changed the background color.
   [image: Hello.storyboard]
3. TabBarItem does not show up in TabBar. (This is Simulator screen capture)
   [image: Simulator]

Anyone knows how to fix this, so I can see the tabBarItem named "item" ?

Xcode7.3 beta (7D152p) OSX 10.11.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself. I just needed to add TabBarItem to ViewController in ViewController.storyboard, not Main.storyboard.